# What exactly are the variables in assembly?

Tags: windows, assembly, windows-10, nasm

I am new to x86 assembly and have been doing some experiments lately using nasm and running the program on a windows 10 machine.

I Have this code:

```
global _start
extern  _GetStdHandle@4
extern  _WriteFile@20
extern  _ExitProcess@4
section .data
    message db "1234"
section .text
_start:
    call print
    call _ExitProcess@4
print:
    ; DWORD  bytes;    
    mov     ebp, esp
    sub     esp, 4

    ; hStdOut = GetstdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
    push    -11
    call    _GetStdHandle@4
    mov     ebx, eax

    ; WriteFile( hstdOut, message, length(message), &bytes, 0);
    push    0
    lea     eax, [ebp-4]
    push    eax
    push    4
    push    message
    push    ebx
    call    _WriteFile@20
    mov     esp, ebp
    ret

    ; ExitProcess(0)
```

That I assemble it using the following commands:

```
nasm -f win32 out.asm
link out.obj /entry:start /subsystem:console "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86\kernel32.lib"
```

and when running it on cmd it outputs "1234" as expected

Now when assembling and running the following code, where instead of pushing message the program pushes "1234" directly

```
global _start
extern  _GetStdHandle@4
extern  _WriteFile@20
extern  _ExitProcess@4
section .data
    message db "1234"
section .text
_start:
    call print
    call _ExitProcess@4
print:
    ; DWORD  bytes;    
    mov     ebp, esp
    sub     esp, 4

    ; hStdOut = GetstdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
    push    -11
    call    _GetStdHandle@4
    mov     ebx, eax

    ; WriteFile( hstdOut, message, length(message), &bytes, 0);
    push    0
    lea     eax, [ebp-4]
    push    eax
    push    4
    push    "1234"
    push    ebx
    call    _WriteFile@20
    mov     esp, ebp
    ret
```

It outputs nothing

Why? What information does message have that "1234" doesn't? When pushing message, does the program just push the address of the memory that is storing "1234"? If so, can I store "1234" somewhere else, and than push its address without creating a variable?

Comment: Yes, you need to pass the address. Yes, you can store it wherever you like. As to whether you consider that a variable or not hardly matters.

Comment: Another way to think about variables in assembly is that they are simply labels for a specific memory address. (e.g. `message db "1234"`, `message` is the address where the beginning byte of `"1234"` is located) When you want what is stored at that address you dereference the variable by enclosing in `[...]`, e.g. `[message]`.

Comment: Ok, tried pushing "1234" before the "push o" line, than moving esp to edi, then pushing edi, instead of "1234" and it seems to be working

Answer (score 5):

A variable is a logical construct — variables have lifetimes, some short, some long.  They can come into being and disappear.

By contrast, registers and memory are physical constructs — in some sense, they are always there.

In assembly programming, by a human or generated by compiler, we make mappings from logical variables needed by our C code, algorithms, and pseudo code, to physical storage available in the processor.  When a variable's lifetime ends, we can reuse the physical storage that it was using for another purpose (another variable).

Assembly language supports global variables (full process lifetime), and local variables — which can be either in memory on the stack, or CPU registers.  CPU registers, of course, do not have addresses, so cannot be passed by (memory) reference.  CPU registers also cannot be indexed, so to index an array requires memory.

Comment: This seems right and usefull to keep in mind, but it doesn't  answer my question. Now, can you elaborate further in the diferences between the logical construct and the physical ones? for exemple, are  the stack and the global variables located in the ram? If so, do I have full access to  the ram thought the stack, or just part of it?(Assuming the OS doesn't block my program)

Comment: The operating system and CPU conspire to virtualize memory, so that each process appears to have its own address space, with similar addresses.  The CPU knows (is programmed by the OS) to know which address space it is working at any point it is executing instructions.  The stack and global memory are simply part of your address space, so they have distinct memory addresses.  As I mentioned, local variables must be in RAM under certain conditions (you want to pass them by reference, or index into them), otherwise they are potential candidates for CPU registers.  Global variables need RAM also.

Comment: Thank you for answering

Answer (score 0):

I would make a local variable on the stack, like this:

```
print:
    ; DWORD  bytes;    
    mov     ebp, esp
    sub     esp, 12

    ; hStdOut = GetstdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
    push    -11
    call    _GetStdHandle@4
    mov     ebx, eax

    lea     ecx, [ebp-12]
    mov     dword ptr [ecx], “1234”

    ; WriteFile( hstdOut, message, length(message), &bytes, 0);
    push    0
    lea     eax, [ebp-4]
    push    eax
    push    4
    push    ecx
    push    ebx
    call    _WriteFile@20
    mov     esp, ebp
    ret
```

Note: the syntax `mov ..., “1234”` may or may not do what you want, depending on the assembler. I don’t remember how the Microsoft assembler handles it. If it doesn’t translate to 0x34333231, then use that constant instead.